# CSS repeat-x for only the right most line of pixels

Tags: css

We currently have our 145x45 header logo set as the background of our mobile header, and have the rest of the header's 'background-color' matching the background of the logo.

The logo has a line a few pixels high across the top of the image, which under the current configuration doesn't extend beyond the image.

How can I make the rightmost 1px(w) x 45px(h) of the logo to fill (repeat-x?) the remainder of the header, so that the line at the top of the image extends across the entire header?

Comment: I don't think you can. One solution might be to create a image without the line and create the whole line in CSS instead. Like `border-top: 5px solid red` on the object containing the image. you might also do this without changing the image if you alter the height of the container object so that the image gets cropped.

Comment: Or create a 1x45 image with the line, use with `repeat-x` in a div, place a div inside that div with the logo image.

Comment: The 1x45 image div>div is my plan if I can't something else work, but this will require changing lots of files, so I was hoping for a pure css solution.

Comment: Nice. I liked my own idea so much that I created an answer.

Comment: BTW the logo lines are repeated vertically on the left side of the logo, and fade off towards the top as you move right, but there is only one line by the time you reach the right side, so an 'image without the line' doesn't really solve it for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a 1x45 image with the line, use with repeat-x in a div, place a div inside that div with the logo image like this:

```
<div style="background-image: url('line_image.png'); background-repeat: repeat-x: height: 45px;">
    <div style="background-image: url('logo.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat; height: 45px;"></div>
</div>
```

Sorry for inline CSS, should be in a .css-file.

PS: Code not testet, let me know if it doesn't work.